# Visual basic variable is used before it has assigned value

Tags: vb.net

this code is the same as others it is a random between 1 and 4 yet for some reason it says it is being used before it has a value it is the same code as 3 others that are the same but with different names yet this is happening can someone please help me?

```
       Dim npc As Random
    Dim ndamage As Integer
    ndamage = npc.Next(1, 4)

    If (Playerhealth.Value - ndamage) <= 0 Then
        Playerhealth.Value = 0
    Else
        Playerhealth.Value = Playerhealth.Value - ndamage
    End If
```

Comment: Among other things, `ndamage` is not the same thing as `damage`

Comment: What is the "it" that's being used before being initialized? Looking at your code, I think it is `Playerhealth.Value`, but I'd like to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first three lines of code,

```
Dim npc As Random
Dim ndamage As Integer
ndamage = npc.Next(1, 4)
```

you declare `npc` and use it before it is assigned a value. You should use `New` to create a new instance:

```
Dim npc As New Random
```

---

**Further Explanation** 
`Random` is a class, which means that its default value is `Nothing` (also called `null` in C#), so before it can be used it needs to be assigned a value. The easiest way in this case is to use `New` directly in the variable declaration line.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget that you can mark an Answer as accepted when it's the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

`Random` is a Class which provides a lot of methods to get different random numbers.

To access these methods you have to create an object (sometimes called instance) of that class.

This is done by the `new` operator. This operator will allocate new space on the heap (which is a memory area) and will fill it with objects values and references to methods and other objects.

If you skip the `new` statement, you program tries to access to not allocated memory. In several languages this will end up in an `nullpointer` exception, in vb.net you get an `used before it has assigned value` exception.

To solve your problem, create an object of the `random` class:

```
Dim npc As New Random
```